# Commas After Conditionals

Tags: punctuation, conditionals

It seems to me that commas for conditionals are falling out of favor. I often see the comma dropped in sentences like:

> If you get stuck in a passive sentence always ask the question:

I would put a comma after *sentence*. But I think my writing ends up with too many commas. How do I decide which ones to drop? Do I just arbitrarily get rid of a few that come after reasonably short conditionals?

Comment: In answer to you're question, most comma usage is subjective. There are some places where they are necessary (e.g. a list of items), but in you're example it's not. Generally commas are omitted from very short sentences. It's your choice as to when to omit a comma in a conditional sentence. I wouldn't say that you should *arbitrarily get rid of* commas, but instead that you should place them to indicate how the sentence should be read.

Answer (score 1):

Commas, like most punctuation, are meant to be a visual indicators of spoken phrasing or inflection. Where your speech calls for a pause, a comma is often used (and sometimes where you should pause but simply run on).

In modern usage, commas are sometimes omitted from very short phrases where the meaning is clear, and a breath is not really needed to separate the clauses or phrases.

In the example you give, I would use the comma as you suggest.

Comment: N.B. It turns out that this is questionable. Phonetically speaking we often don't actually make pauses/mark inflection in the way that we imagine we do-- so while we imagine "pauses" in the place where commas are, when you actually come to look for phonetic gaps/"breaths"/changes in pitch patterns etc, they turn out not to be there. It's probably safer to talk about putting commas where we *perceive* boundaries-- which are often perceptual/syntactic. There's probably circularity involved too: we imagine there's a "pause" *because* there's a piece of punctuation.

Comment: It **was** true once, though.  This was the historical purpose of commas, and it's a purpose they still serve on a regular basis.  But the relationship is no longer quite so clear: sometimes we pause where there is no comma, and we skip over commas without pausing at all.

Comment: @bib:  I suggest a common is optional, for example, in the last sentence of your answer:  "In the example you give I would use the comma as you suggest."  Granted, reading the sentence WITH the comma (i.e., making a brief mental pause after "give"--or a brief, mental pause after "give") would likely prevent having to back up and re-read the sentence, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of commas, like that of all punctuation, is to clarify the grammatical structure of a sentence. It is helpful to place a comma at the end of an *if*-clause, because it signals to the reader that the main clause follows. In your example, the absence of a comma after *sentence* might lead the reader to suppose that the following word, *always*, was part of the *if*-clause. Since no other commas are needed in that sentence, there is no risk of using too many.

Comment: While I think my suggestion about speech is part of the basis for comma use, I also agree with your answer. The cuing about structure is especially important in complex sentences and lists (and even more so for lists that include complex or compound phrases).